# multilingual palindromes"..."

Tags: palindrome

...by which I mean, if you'll forgive the plural, e.g.,

    **state <--> etats**
which is English<-->French for (one particular meaning of) the same word.

So, can you suggest additional examples, English<-->anything-except-English?
There seem to be a reasonable number of English<-->English palindromes, but I couldn't conjure up any other multilingual ones at all. And even this one's pretty trivial (as well as slightly incorrect).

And if you can't conjure up any others, i.e., if it's not just me, then why should same-language palindromes be so much more numerous than multilingual ones? "Backwards" seems pretty syntactically/semantically random/meaningless, whereby you might expect multilingual to be roughly equinumerous with same language.

Comment: Do you require the same meaning or not?  Without that requirement, they should be easy to find; and with that requirement they are rare even in English.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because EL&U only addresses questions about English; questions seeking information about other languages are off-topic (sorry).

Comment: @DanBron This is an English-involving question, at least to the same extent that, say, an etymology question would be. English word origins frequently refer to other languages as well as to English. But, I'd assume you'd agree, that doesn't make such questions off-topic. In other words, I'm suggesting your phrase "questions about English" shouldn't be narrowly construed (in the legal-like sense) to mean "questions **>>only<<** about English".

Comment: @GEdgar Yeah, preferably same meaning. I guess you're right that it should be pretty easy otherwise (though nothing's immediately coming to mind). By the way, "rare even in English" seems wrong. For English<-->English, all palindromes always have the same meaning because you're looking up the same backwards=forwards spelling in exactly the same dictionary.

Comment: You could download some dictionary files in multiple languages (like from the aspell package) then write a quick script to run through the English file and reverse all the words. Then grep for each reversed word in the other language dictionary files.  If you get any matches you can look them up to see what they mean.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a list of trivia and not confined to English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Words aren't just composed of random letter sequences.

Each language has its own set of sounds. These sounds are not equally frequent; some are common and others are rare, and sounds that are shared between two languages might be frequent in one but infrequent in the other.

Each language also has its own set of rules for combining sounds.

And finally, each language has its own set of spelling conventions. For example, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_orthography#Alphabet), the Italian alphabet is ordinarily considered not to include J, K, W, X and Y.

When you're finding palindromes (actually, you are really talking about [half-palindromes](http://www.quotepuzzler.com/info/heteropalindromes.asp)) within a single language, you at least know that the expected letter frequencies will be the same for any two randomly selected words. That is pretty much never true when you're looking for (half⁠-⁠)palindromes between different languages.

Comment: Thanks, sumelic. Sounds reasonable enough, and I doubt anybody's going to suggest anything more reasonable (but I reserve the right to move the "check", just in case:)